# Regex expression for node/express route matching: /api/**/1.2345

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

So far I have:

```
/\/api\/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/
```

Which will match /api/1.234

However I want there to be no limit to the amount of subroutes between /api and /1.2344

For example:

```
/api/hello/there/1.2345
```

should be a valid route. Can anyone help me? this is for a node/express api so it has to be javascript compliant.

It will be implemented into my routes file like this:

```
router.get(/\/api\/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/, api.story);
```

The goal here is that the api recognizes routes that end with a float, because they pertain to story id's in my database, and the subroutes after the api/ and before the /1.12345 are the categories for the sections and sometimes these maybe /section/1.2345 or /section/subsection/1.2345

Thanks!

Comment: What about `/\/api\/(\S+\/)*[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use asterisk `*` to match any string between `\api` and the float number:

```
app.get('/api/*([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)$', function (req, res) {
    res.send('match');
});
```

The above route will respond to `/api/hello/there/1.2345` and `/api/1.2345`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this is exactly what I was searching for.